# How to rollback Bitwise operators on flags

Tags: php

So basically I have various flags representing various states of an entity.
When an action takes place I get the existing flag from the database and store it into $flag variable
and then I do $newflag = $flag | $currentActionFlag; 
And I update the flag in database.

The question is how do I take it back if I want to? If I get the flag for this entity from database now it will be the updated one ($newflag). What do I need to do if I know $newflag and $currentActionFlag in order to get the initial $flag.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You can't get the original flag back after an or operation

Comment: unless you saved the original value somewhere else, it's GONE and you can't get it back. You can always use bitfiddling to set the flag to a particular state, but there's no way to tell what it was BEFORE. You only know what it IS.

Answer (score 0):

$flag = $newflag ^ $currentActionFlag

xor-operator

Comment: This will not work. $newflag will be 1 if $currentActionFlag is 1, regardless of $flag, making it impossible to retrieve the original value of $flag.